# Simple probability question in combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> **Example 4.3a** Suppose that $3$ batteries are randomly chosen from a group of $3$ new, $4$ used but still working, and $5$ defective batteries. If we let $X$ and $Y$ denote, respectively, the number of new and used but still working batteries that are chosen, then the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$, $p(i,j) = P\{X=i,Y=j\}$, is given by
>   $$p(0,0) = \binom{5}{3}/\binom{12}{3} = 10/220.$$

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JIYN.png)

Why does choosing $3$ from $5$ defective batteries result in $\binom{5}{3} = 10$?

In my opinion, we should calculate to probability of choosing $5$ defective from $12$ of overall first $\binom{12}{5}$ and then choosing $3$ from $5$ defective which results in $\binom{5}{3}$. Therefore, final result would be $\binom{12}{5}\binom{5}{3} = 7920$ (sound crazy) not as $\binom{5}{3} = 10.$

Could anyone explain it? I'm new to probability. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: $\binom{12}{5}\binom{5}{3} = 7920 \neq \frac{25}{36}$

Comment: Thanks Max, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple formula for the probability of an event is
$$ \mathbb {P} ( \textrm { Event }) = \frac { \# \textrm { ways event can happen}}{\textrm {total } \# \textrm { ways things can happen}}. $$

You are only doing one round of selection - choosing three batteries.  As there are twelve batteries in total, there are $\binom {12}{3}=220$ ways to choose three batteries in total.

However, there are only $5$ defective batteries. Hence there are $\binom {5}{3}=10$ ways to choose three defective batteries.

Thus the probability of selecting three defective batteries from these twelve is $\frac {10}{220} = \frac {1}{22}$.

Your expression [corrected] of $\binom {12}{5} \binom {5}{3} $ represents first choosing $5$ batteries out of $12$, then choosing $3$ batteries out of those $5$. This leaves three sets of batteries - the $3$ chosen both times, the $2$ only chosen the first time, and the $7$ never chosen at all. That doesn't reflect this situation.

Finally, observe that $\binom {n}{k} $ is the binomial coefficient, and is generally not equal to $\frac {n}{k} $.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, however I don't understand this statement: "This leaves three sets of batteries - the 3 chosen both times, the 2 only chosen the first time, and the 7 never chosen at all." Could you help me get clearer? Thanks

Comment: Suppose we are choosing $3$ batteries to put in a remote, and that you start with $12$ batteries in a box.  Now take $5$ batteries ( $\binom{12}{5}$ options ) out of the box.  From those $5$ batteries, choose $3$ batteries to put in your remote ( $\binom{5}{3}$ options ).  Thus there are a total of $\binom{12}{5} \binom{5}{3}$ ways of doing this.  However, this does not *just* give us $3$ batteries in the remote - it also gives us the other $2$ batteries we took out of the box, along with the $7$ batteries that stay in the box: a total of $3$ sets of batteries.

Comment: However, the problem only asks for making one choice of three batteries, which leaves two sets of batteries: the $3$ we chose, and the $9$ we did not choose.  Hence $\binom{12}{5} \binom{5}{3}$ is overcounting - we are never asked to first choose a set of $5$ batteries (which identifies a further $2$ batteries as being special in some way - as being out of the box in my previous picture).

Comment: Maybe this is overcomplicating things, but I just wanted to explain why $\binom{12}{5} \binom{5}{3}$ is bigger than the answer we are looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help!